# Is it allowed to give physical punishment for women?

Tags: tafseer

according to [following verse](http://www.parsquran.com/data/showall.php?sura=4&ayat=%DB%B3%DB%B4&user=far&lang),is it allowed in Islam physical punishment for women when they do not fulfill conjugal rights in this part of the verse "وَاضْرِبُوهُنَّ"

> الرِّجَالُ قَوَّامُونَ عَلَى النِّسَاء بِمَا فَضَّلَ اللّهُ بَعْضَهُمْ
>   عَلَى بَعْضٍ وَبِمَا أَنفَقُواْ مِنْ أَمْوَالِهِمْ فَالصَّالِحَاتُ
>   قَانِتَاتٌ حَافِظَاتٌ لِّلْغَيْبِ بِمَا حَفِظَ اللّهُ وَاللاَّتِي
>   تَخَافُونَ نُشُوزَهُنَّ فَعِظُوهُنَّ وَاهْجُرُوهُنَّ فِي الْمَضَاجِعِ
>   وَاضْرِبُوهُنَّ فَإِنْ أَطَعْنَكُمْ فَلاَ تَبْغُواْ عَلَيْهِنَّ
>   سَبِيلًا إِنَّ اللّهَ كَانَ عَلِيًّا كَبِيرًا
>
> men are the maintainers of women for that allah has preferred in
>   bounty one of them over another, and for that they have spent of their
>   wealth. righteous women are obedient, guarding in secret that which
>   allah has guarded. those from whom you fear rebelliousness, admonish
>   them and desert them in the bed and leave them. then, if they obey
>   you, do not look for any way against them. allah is high, great.

Answer (score 1):

I will use this translation (Sahih International):

> Men are in charge of women by [right of] what Allah has given one over
>   the other and what they spend [for maintenance] from their wealth. So
>   righteous women are devoutly obedient, guarding in [the husband's]
>   absence what Allah would have them guard. But those [wives] from whom
>   you fear arrogance - [first] advise them; [then if they persist],
>   forsake them in bed; and [finally], strike them. But if they obey you
>   [once more], seek no means against them. Indeed, Allah is ever Exalted
>   and Grand. [4:34](http://quran.com/4/34)

The following points clarified here:

1. Men are the guardians of women.
2. They should provide for them and spend on them from their wealth.
3. Righteous women are obedient of their husbands, and they guard their chastity ("what Allah would have them guard").
4. The first step is to advice.
5. Then, abandon their marital bed.
6. If then they do not right their ways, strike them.

However it does not state here that you should strike the wife if she does not indulge in marital relations.

The problem here is that the word "وَاضْرِبُوهُنَّ" has many meanings, *one* of them is "strike", but it does not always mean the physical act of striking (as in, hitting), however many scholars also suppose another meaning; here is one analysis from [al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/hidden-truths-gods-word-sayyid-mujtaba-musawi-lari/look-meaning-%E2%80%9Cdaraba%E2%80%9D-quran):

> In fact, through a detailed and necessary study of the word
>   “yadribuhunna” (strike them) in the verse, one can infer two distinct
>   meanings, which we will explain in some detail below: The first
>   meaning is derived by considering the apparent meaning of daraba,
>   which is to hit; and the majority lean towards this interpretation.
>
> The second meaning, which is consistent with a study of the context of
>   the matter being discussed in the verse, is an alternate translation
>   of the word daraba, which is a word with several different meanings.
>   One can consider the possibility of this second meaning, which is
>   indignation and disregard, as a response of the man to the nushuz
>   displayed by his wife. This conforms to the extensive meaning of
>   daraba, which includes parting and separation.
>
> Another meaning of daraba is to “turn away from” or “to dispense
>   with”; therefore when referring to the speech of someone who is
>   speaking nonsense, or to a piece of baseless writing, one may say,
>   “fadribuhu ‘ala’l jidar” (throw it at the wall), which is an allegory
>   for, “do not pay attention to it”.

Even if we ignore these interpretations, the Quran provides further guidance:

> Fight in the way of Allah those who fight you but do not transgress.
>   Indeed. Allah does not like transgressors. [2:190](http://quran.com/2:190)

Beating is clearly and act of aggression.

> And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that
>   you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed between you affection
>   and mercy. Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought. [30:21](http://quran.com/30:21)

Clearly Allah prefers mercy and love between a husband and wife, and this is preferred over all else.

Finally, let me leave you with this:

> So high [above all] is Allah , the Sovereign, the Truth. And, [O
>   Muhammad], do not hasten with [recitation of] the Qur'an before its
>   revelation is completed to you, and say, "My Lord, increase me in
>   knowledge." [20:114](http://quran.com/20:114)